# Overlaying two images

Tags: image-processing, image, overlay

I was to superimpose two atom cloud images in Mathematica, with one cloud image centered on the other one. I have tried looking at other threads on this topic but haven't been able to get their solutions to work. I attached the two images to this post. The main issue is that I can't get rid of the white background when I try to overlay the image. Changing the opacity doesn't seem to help either. Ideally I would be able to overlay the images and adjust the transparancy of one relative to the other.

Note: In the final image, one of the clouds will need to be larger than the other by some factor that is ideally variable

[image: atom cloud image]
[image: atom cloud image 2]

Answer (score 7):

You can turn the white material transparent:

```
ImageCompose[img2, ColorReplace[img1, White -> Transparent]]
```

[image]

To change the size, you can ImageResize. Here I have made the resize parameter variable with the slider:

```
Manipulate[ImageCompose[img2, 
  ImageResize[ColorReplace[img1, White -> Transparent], s]], {s, 50, 300, 1}]
```

[image]

There are also several options for the ImageCompose function and you might try them: you can put the object "on top of" or "xor with", etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the alpha channel relative to the pixel brightness - white pixels get transparent, darker pixels get more and more opaque:

```
addAlpha[img_] := 
 SetAlphaChannel[img, 
  ColorNegate[ImageAdjust[ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"]]]]
```

Then you can use `ImageCompose` to combine them:

```
{a, b} = Import /@ {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPsWy.jpg", 
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSvA2.jpg"};    
ImageCompose[b, addAlpha[a], {0, 0}, {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Or `Inset` to place the semitransparent images in another graphic:

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[5 x], Cos[7 x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
 Epilog -> {
   Inset[addAlpha[a], {0, .5}, Center, 2],
   Inset[addAlpha[b], {.5, 0}, Center, 3]
   }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
img1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPsWy.jpg"]
img2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSvA2.jpg"]
```

The images have different dimensions

```
ImageDimensions /@ {img1, img2}
```

> {{61, 42}, {150, 103}}

and as noted some white frame, which can be removed with

```
{c1, c2} = ImageCrop /@ {img1, img2}
```

They still have different dimensions

```
ImageDimensions /@ {c1, c2}
```

> {{47, 32}, {115, 78}}

so we'll resize the smaller one

```
im1 = ImageResize[c1, ImageDimensions@c2]
im2 = c2 (* for consistency of the naming *)
```

There are different way to compose the images, e.g.

```
ImageExposureCombine[{im1, im2}]
```

[image]

```
ImageMultiply[im1, im2]
```

[image]

```
Blend[{im1, im2}]
```

[image]

Comment: So I actually need one of the clouds to look larger than the other, which is why I had the images be different sizes originally

Comment: There are another function `ConformImages` can uniform the image size.